# Weird Error when trying to code a todo app

Tags: javascript

Just playing with JavaScript and I got an error an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at app.js:22

The code in my JavaScript file error line is:

```
if (data) {
    LIST = JSON.parse("TODO");
} else  {
    
}
```

Comment: The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string therefore you need to pass your data into the function like var LIST = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: `JSON.parse("TODO");` how odd, D is in position 2 not 0 - chrome states `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0` ... so, what does your code really look like?

Comment: @Noob - `a JSON string, not a regular string` ??? JSON string is a "regular" string - of course, JSON.parse will only parse a string that contains valid JSON :p

Comment: my Code is this: if (data) {                                                                                                     
                                 LIST = JSON.parse(data);                                                                       
                          } else {                                                                                                           
                          }

Comment: @JaromandaX well that's kind of what I meant :)

Comment: So how do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` will only work on strings or string variables that represent a JSON object, like

```
"
   'item1': 50,
   'item2': 80,
   'item3': 100
"
```

in order to parse them into JSON objects

As you can tell, "TODO" cannot be parsed into a JSON object, but perhaps in your code there is a variable `data` which is a string representing JSON object. Most likely you will need to change that line to:

```
    LIST = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `json.parse` on wrong data type.`json.parse` is made for objects while you are passing a string `JSON.parse("TODO")`. Note that "TODO" is a string and not an object.

Follow this example:

```
const todo = '{"name":"Empty the trash"}'

const obj = JSON.parse(todo);
```